# Parallel fundamental vector fields

Tags: connections, principal-bundles

Suppose I have a principal bundle $P$ relative to the group $G$. Suppose I have a torsionless connection on $TP$ for which the fundamental vector fields relative to the $G$ action are parallel. Can I conclude that the bundle is trivial? If this is true can I conclude the connection is a product connection?

Comment: So edit your post to include a precise statement of how you would verify that the fundamental vector field is parallel.

Comment: Ok I don't understand this comment, but all the same it made me realize that my question made no sense since it makes no sense to ask for the fundamental vector fields to be parallel for a connection on $P$ rather than on $TP$... I edited the question to ask what I actually needed to know