# Parallel fundamenal vector fields on circle bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

Since [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4413343/parallel-fundamental-vector-fields) question received no answer, let me go through a simpler case first.
Let $P$ be a $U(1)$-bundle and suppose I have a metric on it that makes the fundamental vector field of the action parallel (for example if the metric is invariant under the circle action and the total manifold is Ricci flat). Can I conclude the circle bundle is trivial?

Comment: It may be helpful for you to provide an example where this property is true, both to provide evidence that such a claim could be true and also to give readers a sense of how to prove it in general.

Comment: What happens with the Hopf bundle?